# Finding distance between 2 devices

Tags: networking, bluetooth, wifi, device, router

I wanted to know if there is any efficient way of finding the distance between 2 devices(a transmitter and a receiver) which is accurate to atleast the order of a couple of inches.

I am basically want to detect the movement of the transmitter from the receiver and how far it has moved from its original position.

I was thinking in terms of using a wireless hotspot/bluetooth connection. I cannot Use some form of audio/medium which can be detected by humans.
Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, assuming there is no common synchronisation signal between the devices, there are 2 differents way to do this (not really easy):

**1. Measure received power :** some receivers provide RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indication). RSSI is a measure of how much power you received. If you know the transmitted power, you can estimate the transmission loss (from the transsmission channel) by taking different measure of RSSI at different distance. It will really depends on the channel (environment, frequency, throughput, ..), so don't change it for the measure. Once you got enough points, try to fit it by a curve. You can now predict distance by having RSSI.

**2. Measure round trip time :** this is called RADAR, and is really more difficult but is the classic way to measure distance and speed. Broadband systems (like WiFi) are better for this kind of measure. By the way you also can do the same with audio for short distances (SONAR), without being detected if you use frequencies higher than 20kHz.